# Load html from SQLite database and images from assets?

Tags: android, sqlite, webview, android-assets

I am developing a android app, I need some help from experts, my scenario is below.

I am storing html(text) in SQlite database, in that html I have some images, can I load those images from assets folder.

I load html from database, images(src) in that html should point to assets folder.

Please add your suggestions and comments.

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: Please add more information: what did you do so far, what's actually the real question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the corresponding uri in the `src` attribute of your `img` elements using the `file:///android_asset/your_image.png` uri schema. For example...

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/image_name.png" />
```

Make sure you specify the base url when loading the html into the `WebView`

```
webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```